# Should I use an object with an id or an array with an index for selecting value?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects, rendering

Let's say I have a database of users.

```
user1: {'name': 'John'}
user2: {'name': 'Sue'}
...
```

I can either create an array of users

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([user1, user2,...])
```

And I can select a user with an index `array[index]`

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const selectedUser = array[index];
return <h2>{selectedUser.name}</h2>
```

Or I can create an object with id's as their keys.

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({'user1': {'name': 'John'},...})
```

And I can select a user by just saving their id `obj['user1']`.

```
const [id, setId] = useState('user1');
const selectedUser= obj[id];
return <h2>{selectedUser.name}</h2>
```

Which one is better for selecting a user and then using the data for rendering? Is there any major difference in performance or memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend using objects.

You can do everything on them as you would on an array and more. For example finding an element in an array with a specific `name` has the performance advantage considering an object. Finding it in an object (if the key is the `name`) finding it is O(1), while in an array you have to iterate over all elements (so O(n)).

In your case, if you know the index, it doesn't really matter which one you use.